# How to find references from external documents in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

When I use the following line in `index.ts`:

`///<reference path='Classes/Core.ts' />`

I get errors in `Core.ts` for elements that are derivatived from `index.ts`.

How can I 'tell' Core.ts to look in the other .ts files for references?

Comment: Shouldn't be a file.d.ts file?

Answer (score 0):

If you use internal modules - it seems that you have problem with names or types.. can you please make an example?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I 'tell' Core.ts to look in the other .ts files for references?

Please don't use `reference` comments in your code anymore. Use a `tsconfig.json` file to drive the *compilation context*: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/compilation-context.html